# With having two dates now i month wise days calculation required

Tags: excel, vba

I have two dates. Now my aim is to calculate the number of days, month wise for `n` number of rows

Input:

```
start date    22/01/2019
finish date   21/06/2019
```

Output & result should be

```
January February   March    April   May     June
9       28         31       30      31      21
```

for many rows.

Excel or VBA Excel formula both will be great,
Thanks in advance....

Here is a screenshot of my Excel table:
https://ibb.co/tC38jzs

Comment: And what have you tried...?

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution if your *Active Month* column entries are not the names of the month, but the last day.

```
31.01.2019  28.02.2019  ...
```

For the January column you can then use

```
=MAX(0, MIN($AV14-$AT14, AY$13-$AV14))
```

and for the other months you have to subtract the days aggregated since January. Here for February:

```
=MAX(0, MIN($AV14-$AT14, AZ$13-$AV14) - SUM($AY14:AY14))
```

Expand the last formula from Feb to Dec.